# How to upload DevExtreme ios app from windows?

Tags: devexpress

I want to upload my iOS app, created by Visual Studio 2012 DevExtreme Project to iOS app store via iTunes connect. But according to the website and other reference website it says that a Mac device is needed to upload the app on to the store.

Is there any way that I could do that without using Mac (e.g from my windows 8 PC)
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/can_i_upload_my_app_to_itunes_connect_from_a_windows_pc_without_using_a_mac

Thanks & regards
Rudresh Bhatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good workaround for uploading an iOS application to the App Store using Windows. Anyway, all workarounds require Mac in the end to sign and send an app to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

What about a virtual machine (such as one hosted by VMWare Workstation) running a Mac OS? Would that work?